Proof the linear independence of a set of exponential functions multiplied by polynomial terms using induction
Given $n_i$ positive integrers and $c_i \in \mathbb{C}$ distinct complex numbers $(0 \leq i \leq k)$ How can I show that the following set is linearly independent on $C^{\infty}$ using induction over $k$ or any other method which involves linear algebra?
$\beta = \lbrace e^{c_1 t},te^{c_1 t},...,t^{n-1}e^{c_1 t},...,e^{c_k t},te^{c_k t},...t^{n-1}e^{c_k t} \rbrace$
Things I think can be helpful which I've already proven:
$1. \forall c \in \mathbb{C}$, the differential operator $D-CI: C^{\infty} \rightarrow C^{\infty}$ is onto.
$2.\lbrace e^{c_1 t}, e^{c_2 t},..., e^{c_k t} \rbrace$ is l.i.
$3. \forall c \in \mathbb{C}$, $\lbrace e^{c t}, te^{c t},...,t^{n-1}e^{c t} \rbrace$ is l.i.
$4. \forall c \in \mathbb{C}$, $\forall k$ positive integrer, if   $k<n$ $\Rightarrow$ $\left(D-CI \right)^{n} \left( t^k e^{ct} \right) =0$
$5.$ In general, $\forall m $ positive integrers, $\forall c \in \mathbb{C}$, $\left(D-cI \right) \left( t^m e^{ct} \right) = m t^{m-1} e^{ct}$
$5.$ Differential operators conmute and, since the composition of lineal operators that are onto, is also onto, we have that differential operators of any order are onto.
Proof by induction over $k$.
The case $k=1$ follows from $3.$
Suppose that the theorem is valid for $k-1$. Let $b_{ij} \in \mathbb{C}$ $\left( 1 \leq i \leq k, 0 \leq j \leq n_i -1\right)$ such that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{n_i -1} b_{ij}t^j e^{c_i t} = 0
\end{equation}
Applying the diferencial operator $\left(D-CI \right)^{n_k}$ to both sides of the equation, by
linearity of the operator, we obtain
\begin{align}
0 &= \sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{n_i-1} b_{ij} \left(D-CI \right)^{n_k} \left[ t^j e^{c_i t} \right] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \sum_{j=0}^{n_i -1} b_{ij} \left(D-CI \right)^{n_k} \left[ t^j e^{c_i t} \right] + \sum_{j=0}^{n_k -1} b_{kj} \left(D-CI \right)^{n_k} \left[ t^j e^{c_k t} \right] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \sum_{j=0}^{n_i -1} b_{ij} \left(D-CI \right)^{n_k} \left[ t^j e^{c_i t} \right]
\end{align}
The last term of the sum vanishes because $0 \leq j \leq n_k -1 < n_k$ and applying $4.$
With this we can apply the inductive hypothesis and know the coefficients for all terms in the resulting sum are zero. The question is if obtaining those terms are the part I'm missing to conclude something, or is there any other way to proof this. My guess is that there must be a explicit formula to obtain $\left(D-CI \right)^{n_k} \left[ t^j e^{c_i t} \right]$ in separated terms that include the $b_{ij}$'s.
The first derivation results in a cumbersome equation which can be used recursively. Observe that
$\left( D-c_k I\right) \left[ t^j e^{c_i t}\right] = j t^{j-1}e^{c_it} + (c_i - c_k)t^je^{c_it}$
$\left( D-c_k I\right)^{2} \left[ t^j e^{c_i t}\right] =j(j-1)t^{j-2}e^{c_i t} +2j(c_i - c_k)t^{j-1}e^{c_i t} + (c_i -c_k)^2 t^j e^{c_i t}$
$\left( D-c_k I\right)^{3} \left[ t^j e^{c_i t}\right] =j(j-1)(j-2)t^{j-3}e^{c_i t} +3j(j-1)(c_i - c_k)t^{j-2}e^{c_i t} + 3j(c_i -c_k)^2 t^{j-1} e^{c_i t}+ (c_i - c_k)^3 t^j e^{c_i t}$
Which somewhat suggest a Pascal's triangle expansion.
Intuitively, for $\left( D-c_k I\right)^{n_k}$ I suspect that the coefficient of the term $t^{n_i -1}e^{c_i t}$ will be $(c_i -c_k)^{n_k}b_{i n_i -1}=0$ by H.I. which means $b_{i n_i -1}=0$ $\forall i<k$ because the complex numbers are distinct. With the remaining terms, something similar should happen until we are left with something I can conclude with $3.$
This is part of an exercise from Friedberg's Lineal Algebra 4th edition, chapter 2.7, exercise 11/Theorem 2.34.
